# Как перенести данные из XML в SQLite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Я пытаюсь разобрать xml файл :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document>
  <data id="trades">
    <metadata>
      <columns>
        <column name="TRADENO" type="int64" />
        <column name="TRADETIME" type="time" bytes="10" max_size="0" />
        <column name="BOARDID" type="string" bytes="12" max_size="0" />
        <column name="SECID" type="string" bytes="36" max_size="0" />
        <column name="PRICE" type="double" />
        <column name="QUANTITY" type="int32" />
        <column name="VALUE" type="double" />
        <column name="PERIOD" type="string" bytes="3" max_size="0" />
        <column name="TRADETIME_GRP" type="int32" />
        <column name="SYSTIME" type="datetime" bytes="19" max_size="0" />
        <column name="BUYSELL" type="string" bytes="3" max_size="0" />
        <column name="DECIMALS" type="int32" />
      </columns>
    </metadata>
    <rows>
      <row TRADENO="2601009073" TRADETIME="09:59:45" BOARDID="TQBR" SECID="AFLT" PRICE="82.92" QUANTITY="2" VALUE="16584" PERIOD="S" TRADETIME_GRP="959" SYSTIME="2016-06-14 09:59:45" BUYSELL="S" DECIMALS="2" />
      <row TRADENO="2601009074" TRADETIME="09:59:45" BOARDID="TQBR" SECID="AFLT" PRICE="82.92" QUANTITY="1" VALUE="8292" PERIOD="S" TRADETIME_GRP="959" SYSTIME="2016-06-14 09:59:45" BUYSELL="S" DECIMALS="2" />
      <row TRADENO="2601009075" TRADETIME="09:59:45" BOARDID="TQBR" SECID="AFLT" PRICE="82.92" QUANTITY="1" VALUE="8292" PERIOD="S" TRADETIME_GRP="959" SYSTIME="2016-06-14 09:59:45" BUYSELL="S" DECIMALS="2" />
      <row TRADENO="2601009076" TRADETIME="09:59:45" BOARDID="TQBR" SECID="AFLT" PRICE="82.92" QUANTITY="4" VALUE="33168" PERIOD="S" TRADETIME_GRP="959" SYSTIME="2016-06-14 09:59:45" BUYSELL="S" DECIMALS="2" />
      <row TRADENO="2601009077" TRADETIME="09:59:45" BOARDID="TQBR" SECID="AFLT" PRICE="82.92" QUANTITY="1" VALUE="8292" PERIOD="S" TRADETIME_GRP="959" SYSTIME="2016-06-14 09:59:45" BUYSELL="S" DECIMALS="2" />
      <row TRADENO="2601009078" TRADETIME="09:59:45" BOARDID="TQBR" SECID="AFLT" PRICE="82.92" QUANTITY="8" VALUE="66336" PERIOD="S" TRADETIME_GRP="959" SYSTIME="2016-06-14 09:59:45" BUYSELL="S" DECIMALS="2" />
      <row TRADENO="2601009079" TRADETIME="09:59:45" BOARDID="TQBR" SECID="AFLT" PRICE="82.92" QUANTITY="1" VALUE="8292" PERIOD="S" TRADETIME_GRP="959" SYSTIME="2016-06-14 09:59:45" BUYSELL="S" DECIMALS="2" />
    </rows>
  </data>
  <data id="dataversion">
    <metadata>
      <columns>
        <column name="version" type="int32" />
        <column name="seqnum" type="int32" />
      </columns>
    </metadata>
    <rows>
      <row version="4821" seqnum="631768" />
    </rows>
  </data>
</document>
```

С помощью этого кода:

```
#!\usr\bin\dev python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request
import sqlite3
import xml.etree.ElementTree

urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.micex.ru/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/securities/AFLT/trades.xml", "tradesAFLT.xml")


def insert_trade(db_conn, TRADENO, TRADETIME, BOARDID, SECID, PRICE, QUANTITY, VALUE, PERIOD, TRADETIME_GRP, SYSTIME, BUYSELL, DECIMALS):
    curs = db_conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("insert into AFLT values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    (TRADENO, TRADETIME, BOARDID, SECID, PRICE, QUANTITY, VALUE, PERIOD, TRADETIME_GRP, SYSTIME, BUYSELL, DECIMALS))
    db_conn.commit()

def trade_data_from_element(element):
    TRADENO = element.find("TRADENO").text
    TRADETIME = element.find("TRADETIME").text
    BOARDID = element.find("BOARDID").text
    SECID = element.find("SECID").text
    PRICE = element.find("PRICE").text
    QUANTITY = element.find("QUANTITY").text
    VALUE = element.find("VALUE").text
    PERIOD = element.find("PERIOD").text
    TRADETIME_GRP = element.find("TRADETIME_GRP").text
    SYSTIME = element.find("SYSTIME").text
    BUYSELL = element.find("BUYSELL").text
    DECIMALS = element.find("DECIMALS").text
    return TRADENO, TRADETIME, BOARDID, SECID, PRICE, QUANTITY, VALUE, PERIOD, TRADETIME_GRP, SYSTIME, BUYSELL, DECIMALS

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Tradestatistics.sqlite3")
    tradesAFLT = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("tradesAFLT.xml")
    document = tradesAFLT.findall("document")
    for index, element in enumerate(document):
        TRADENO, TRADETIME, BOARDID, SECID, PRICE, QUANTITY, VALUE, PERIOD, TRADETIME_GRP, SYSTIME, BUYSELL, DECIMALS = trade_data_from_element(element)
        insert_trade(TRADENO, TRADETIME, BOARDID, SECID, PRICE, QUANTITY, VALUE, PERIOD, TRADETIME_GRP, SYSTIME, BUYSELL, DECIMALS)
```

Но никак не могу понять, как это правильно сделать.
Интерпретатор прогоняет скрипт.Ошибок не выдает, но в базу данных ничего не добавляется.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Похоже вы забыли передать `conn`... Попробуйте: `insert_trade(conn, TRADENO, ...)`

Answer (score 3):

я бы делал это при помощи BeautifulSoup и Pandas:

```
import os
import requests
import sqlite3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import pandas as pd

url = 'd:/download/trades.xml'
#url = 'http://www.micex.ru/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/securities/AFLT/trades.xml'
db_path = 'd:/temp/Tradestatistics.sqlite3'

if os.path.isfile(url):
    with open(url) as f:
        soup = bs4(f, 'lxml')
else:
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        r.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4(r.text, 'lxml')

df = pd.DataFrame([x.attrs for x in soup.find_all('row')])

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)

df.to_sql('AFLT', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```